# JSON error while populating a listview

Tags: android, json, listview

i have this code below :

```
package com.example.test.center;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Posts extends Activity {
String type,firstname,lastname,email,number,username;   
HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle gotBasket=getIntent().getExtras();
        type=gotBasket.getString("type_post");
       this.setTitle(type);

        setContentView(R.layout.addpost);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.38/LTC/Uploadposts.php?type="+type+"");
 try{
 nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type",type));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
 {

 entity=response.getEntity();
 if(entity !=null)
 {
    InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
 //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),jsonResponse.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 String retUser=jsonResponse.getString("username");// username is the name of a column
 String retcont=jsonResponse.getString("Content");
 String getf=jsonResponse.getString("FirstN");
String getl=jsonResponse.getString("LastN");
String dop=jsonResponse.getString("Dateofp");


try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse.toString());

    int jArrayLength = jArray.length();
    List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(jArrayLength);

    for(int i =0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        listContents.add(json_data.getString("username"));

    }

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));

}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag","Error parsin data "+e.toString());
}

 }}

 }//End of first try

 catch(Exception e)
 {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 } // End of first catch



    } //End of oncreate bundle



      private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
       {


       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String line = null;
       try
       {

       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
       }catch(IOException e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally
       {
        try{
            is.close();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }return sb.toString();



       }


} //End of Class
```

It's not reading properly the json format, i want to take the result of my php file (the result is in json format) and store it in a json array then take the value each time of the "username" column and load it in the listview.  Any help ?

Comment: what is the error post your logs

Comment: I cannot understand why you added `php` tag since you are not showing any script related to it.

Comment: Also post your JSON string

Comment: this is the error : Error parsin data org.json.JSONException : Value {"username":"you","Dateofp":"2013-03-03","Content":"test1","IDpost:"1","LastN":"Yaghi","Type":"CARS","FirstN":"Mounzer"} of type org.json.JSONobject cannot be converted to json array

Comment: @moonwalker : post your full json String which u are getting from server or share link from with u are retrieving json

Comment: your are getting a jsonobject , JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse.toString()); will give u error...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK this is the full string : {"IDpost":"1","username":"you","FirstN":"Mounzer","LastN":"Yaghi","Content":"test1","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-03"}{"IDpost":"2","username":"boss","FirstN":"Marwan","LastN":"Geha","Content":"test2\r\n","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-05"}

Comment: @baboo what should i do to correct this error ?

Comment: check my edit in answer but first thing can u change the JSON response coming from serverr or just change ur android code.. ?

Comment: @moonwalker : your json String is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For above code to work enclose your json Response with [].. you are getting a JSonObject and you are trying to parse it as JSONARRAY... 
So for above code to work convert response to

```
      [{"username":"you","Dateofp":"2013-03-03","Content":"test1","IDpost:"1","LastN":"‌​    Yaghi","Type":"CARS","FirstN":"Mounzer"}]
```

or Use simple JSON object parsing and add the object in listContents.. remove code relating to
 JSONARRAY

CHange

```
  {"IDpost":"1","username":"you","FirstN":"Mounzer","LastN":"Yaghi","Content":"tes‌​t1","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-03"}{"IDpost":"2","username":"boss","FirstN"‌​:"Marwan","LastN":"Geha","Content":"test2\r\n","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-0‌​5"}
```

to

```
  [{"IDpost":"1","username":"you","FirstN":"Mounzer","LastN":"Yaghi","Content":"tes‌​t1","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-03"},{"IDpost":"2","username":"boss","FirstN"‌​:"Marwan","LastN":"Geha","Content":"test2\r\n","Type":"CARS","Dateofp":"2013-03-0‌​5"}]
```

Notice the "[" "]" added and "," in between two objects..

Comment: thanks a lot it really worked, but I'm getting only one row from the table. The table contains two rows

Comment: u mean server side issue , from ur server u are sending one row or from server u sending two and in android it displays one ?

Comment: from the server I'm sending 2 rows, but in android it's only taking one row.I only made that change in my code :
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("["+jsonResponse.toString()+"]");

Comment: what abt adding the COMA "," in between the two objects?? json array structure needs a ", " in btw objects.. it shld be before {"IDpost":"2" and after "Dateofp":"2013-03-03"}

Comment: Well I've told u the only change I made in my code above is this :
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("["+jsonResponse.toString()+"]");
Where should I add the COMA here ?

Comment: if u dont have control over server side add a "," after each "}" u encounter , not a pretty solution .. best is get the SERVER side guy and fix the structure of JSON array he returns, if not possible then try the dirty solution of regex replacing each "}" with "}," except the last object or "}" encountered dont add "," there.  ... good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that: `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse.toString());`
jsonResponse contains JSONObject not JSONArray